# How to resize an image according to a reference point in another

Tags: python-3.x, python-imaging-library

I currently have two images (im1 and im2) with pixel dimensions of (1725, 1580). im2 however possesses a large border around it that i had to create to ensure that the images were of the same size. im2 was originally (1152, 864).

As such. when i overlay im2 ontop of im1 using `PIL.Image.blend`, im2 appears overlayed onto im1, but is a lot smaller. I have 2 distinct reference points on the images i think i could use (present on im1 and im2) to rescale im2 (zoom it in somehow?) to  overlay im2 ontop of im1.

My issue is that i have been looking through various python modules (PIL, scipy, matplotlib etc) but cant seem to really be getting anywhere or find a solution with which i could approach this issue.

I have 2 reference points i think i could use (present on im1 and im2) to rescale im2 (zoom it in somehow?) to  overlay im2 ontop of im1.

i have looked at various modules but cant to seem to find anything that might work (scipy, PIL, matplotlib)

```
#im1 https://i.imgur.com/dF8uyPw.jpg
#im2 https://i.imgur.com/o4RAhOQ.png
#im2_resized https://i.imgur.com/jfWz1LE.png

im1 = Image.open("pit5Film/Pit_5_5mm_inf.tif")
im2 = Image.open("pit5Overlay/overlay_132.png")

old_size = im2.size
new_size = im1.size
im2_resized = Image.new("RGB", new_size) 
im2_resized.paste(im2,((round((new_size[0]-old_size[0])/2)),round(((new_size[1]-old_size[1])/2))))

Image.blend(im1,im2_resized,0.2)
```

Comment: Have you tried calling the `resize` method?

Comment: i havd had a go at using the resize function avialable in the PIL.Image module. With that i have been able to change the relative size of im2, which is great. But that is only half the problem. As my aim is to somehow resize it so that it is at the exact same scale as im1. then overlay the two images accoridng to reference points

Comment: So you want image correlation algorithms? Or the math to align the images given known points?

Comment: Show what you've done with resize, since there are no answers yet, and explain what your inputs are to align the images please.

Comment: i have attached links to the images as they stand. basically i am attempting overlay im2 onto im1 using the two circular points on either sides of the images as reference points

Comment: The main issue i have with directly reizing im2 to that of im1 ie via ```im2.resize((1725,1580))``` is that it distorts im2. i am aiming to effectively "zoom in" on im2, so that the 2 reference points are the same distance apart in im1 and im2.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are trying to do an *"affine distortion"*. I can maybe work out how to do it in **OpenCV** or **PIL**, but for the minute, here's what I did with **ImageMagick**.

First, I located the centre of the registration hole (?) on both the left and right side of the first image. I got these coordinates:

```
422,775    # left hole centre 1st picture
1246,799   # right hole centre 1st picture
```

[image]

Then I found these same features in the second picture at:

```
514,426    # left hole centre 2nd picture
668,426    # right hole centre 2nd picture
```

[image]

Then I ran this in Terminal to do the 2-point affine transformation:

```
convert imageA.jpg -virtual-pixel white                        \
    -distort affine '422,775 514,426 1246,799 668,426' +repage \
    imageB.png -compose overlay -composite result.jpg
```

[image]

There is loads of great information from Anthony Thyssen [here](https://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/distorts/) if you fancy a read.

Comment: That is exactly what i am trying to achieve as an outputted image! The plan is to have it as a python script that can be run to align both images. ImageMagick is an external piece of software i take it from the looks of it? From the looks of what you have done i think an "affine distortion" is exactly what i am after.

Comment: Cool - I can see it as `transform()` in PIL/Pillow, but I think that may be limited, so we will probably need to use OpenCV along these lines... https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_geometric_transformations/py_geometric_transformations.html

Comment: Oh, there is also Python `wand` which is a Python binding to ImageMagick... http://docs.wand-py.org/en/0.5.5/guide/distortion.html?highlight=distort

Comment: Maybe Eric @emcconville (who I believe is now maintaining and developing Wand?) will be kind enough to step in with a Wand-based answer?

Answer (score 1):

This is how to do it in Python Wand, which is based upon Imagemagick. I use Mark Setchell's images and the Python Wand equivalent command. The distort command needs Imagemagick 7, according to the documentation. Using Python Wand 0.5.5, the current version.

**Script:**

```
#!/bin/python3.7

from wand.image import Image
from wand.color import Color
from wand.display import display

with Image(filename='imageA.jpg') as Aimg:
    with Image(filename='imageB.jpg') as Bimg:
        Aimg.virtual_pixel = 'background'
        Aimg.background_color = Color('white')
        arguments = (422, 775, 514, 426, 1246, 799, 668, 426)
        Aimg.distort('affine', arguments)
        Aimg.composite(Bimg, 0, 0, 'overlay')
        Aimg.save(filename='image_BoverlayA_composite.png')
        display(Aimg)
```

**Calling Command:**

```
python3.7 wand_affine_overlay.py
```

**Result:**
[image]

**ADDITION:**

If you want to trim the image to its minimum bounding box, then add trim to the command as follows, where the trim value is in the range 0 to quantum range.

```
#!/bin/python3.7

from wand.image import Image
from wand.color import Color
from wand.display import display

with Image(filename='imageA.jpg') as Aimg:
    with Image(filename='imageB.jpg') as Bimg:
        Aimg.virtual_pixel = 'background'
        Aimg.background_color = Color('white')
        arguments = (422, 775, 514, 426, 1246, 799, 668, 426)
        Aimg.distort('affine', arguments)
        Aimg.composite(Bimg, 0, 0, 'overlay')
        Aimg.trim(fuzz=10000)
        Aimg.save(filename='image_BoverlayA_composite.png')
        display(Aimg)
```

[image]

Comment: Go on, add a `trim()` at the end ;-)

Comment: Mark, OK, but I was just emulating your command. I was puzzled by why your image was smaller.

Answer (score 0):

batter way for resizing an image using OpenCV

```
dim = (width, height)
# resize image
resized = cv2.resize(img, dim, interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)
```

for blend two images using OpenCV
1: load both image

```
src1 = cv.imread(cv.samples.findFile('img1.jpg'))
src2 = cv.imread(cv.samples.findFile('img2.jpg'))
```

2: blend both images (alpha is in  between 0 to 1 any float)

```
beta = (1.0 - alpha)
dst = cv.addWeighted(src1, alpha, src2, beta, 0.0)
```

3: for displaying  result

```
cv.imshow('dst', dst)
cv.waitKey(0)
```

if you wont to resize an image according to a reference point consider this awsome blog by PYIMAGESEARCH : [PYIMAGESEARCH 4 POINT](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2014/08/25/4-point-opencv-getperspective-transform-example/)