# Python PIL: Rotate and scale image so that two points match two other points

Tags: python, geometry, python-imaging-library

Say I have an image with two points in it.

```
pointA = (100,100)
pointB = (200,200)
```

I want to **rotate and scale** the image so that both points are now in different locations.

```
newPointA = (250,320)
newPointB = (540, 330)
```

In pseudocode I am looking for something like this

```
adjusted = im.transformToPoint(originalA, originalB, newA, newB)
```

In other words, how scaling and rotating would work on a touchscreen device if pointA and pointB are the fingers when they touch down and newPointA and newPointB are the fingers when they lift up.

Black borders being created is not a problem.

I know that this is likely a simple operation since it is how scaling and rotating with two fingers works on touchscreen devices, but unfortunately, my understanding of geometry is too limited to figure it out.

Comment: You might like to read this https://stackoverflow.com/a/57058389/2836621 and also Fred's @fmw42 answer with a Python implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A rotation wtih angle **A** around the origin can be expressed  as

```
xNew = xOld·cos(A) - yOld·sin(A)
yNew = xOld·sin(A) + yOld·cos(A)
```

Scaling with factor **F**, again from the origin is

```
xScaled = xBase · F
yScaled = yBase · F
```

You may say that having two (x,y) points and their final transformed points the problem is solved by plugging those into the equations and solving the system. But the issue is that the system is not easy to solve; you'll need some numeric aproximation.

But not everything is lost :)

The angle **B** between two points is easily calculated: Take the increments `dx=x2-x1` and `dy=y2-y1` and use `B= atan2(dx,dy)` (prevent yourself from `atan(dx,dy)`). Using before/after movement touchs you get two angles. The angle of rotation is `A= B2-B1`.

The scaling factor **F** is also easy: Calculate the distances between fingers in the touch and after the fingers' movement. The factor is the quotient between them.

Note:

I think you also need a **translation**, otherwise your final image may be not what you expect.

What I'd do is:

1. First calculate the middle point between fingers `(mx,my)` in the touch action. Also calculate the angle of rotation **A** and the scale factor  **F** using both touch an lift actions.
2. Then translate the whole image so that its origin becomes that middle point. Just
   substract those middle coordinates `(mx,my)`.
3. Then rotate and scale.
4. Then undo the translation, by adding the stored middle coordinates used before.

In step '1.' I'm supposing that the rotation happens around the middle point. You may consider other point. For example if the finger "one" does not move a lot, but finger "two" does, it can be that the rotation/scaling is around coordinates of finger "one". If so, use these coodinates.

Perhaps the general case to obtain that "middle" point is to calculate the intersection of the lines finger-one-to-finger-two at touch and lift actions.